# AbstractMethodError when Mocking MultipartFile in Spring Boot Test

Tags: java, spring, kotlin, mockk

I'm trying to mock a MultipartFile in a Spring Boot test using the Mockk library. I'm experiencing an issue where I get an AbstractMethodError when calling the getContentType() method on the mocked file.

Error message:
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Receiver class org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile$Subclass0 does not define or inherit an implementation of the resolved method 'abstract java.lang.String getContentType()' of interface org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile.

Code:
Here's the test where I'm encountering the issue:

```
import io.mockk.every
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test
import org.springframework.http.MediaType
import org.springframework.mock.web.MockMultipartFile
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.multipart
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status
import test.dto.PdfDocumentResponseDto
import test.service.S3FileService

class PdfDocumentControllerIntegrationTest {

lateinit var mockMvc: MockMvc

lateinit var s3FileService: S3FileService

@Test
fun `should upload file`() {
    val mockFile = MockMultipartFile("file", "test.pdf", "application/pdf", "test data".toByteArray())
    val responseDto = PdfDocumentResponseDto(
        pdfDocumentFilePath = "test-path.com"
    )

    every { s3FileService.uploadFile(any()) } returns responseDto

    mockMvc.perform(multipart("/v1/pdf-test-service/pdf")
        .file(mockFile)
        .contentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA))
        .andExpect(status().isOk)
}
}
```

Environment:

Spring Boot version "3.0.5"
Mockk version: 3.0.1"
Kotlin version: "1.7.22"
Operating System: macOS

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

I've tried using a custom stub implementation of MultipartFile and passing that to the mockMvc.perform() method, but the .file() method only accepts MockMultipartFile objects.

Comment: You could try to extend MockMultipartFile. From what I can see it's not final.